# How to change viewcontroller on buttonTapped with iCarousel?

Tags: switch-statement, viewcontroller, icarousel

I have a viewcontroller with an iCarousel.

When I tap on an item that I know how to display an UIalert but, now I want to  change view controller to go on an other already created viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need something like this:

```
MyOtherViewControllersName *vc =[[MyOtherViewControllersName alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyOtherViewControllersName" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Just put it in the same method where you're generating the alert message.